# New DDos Attack on WordPress website

Tags: wordpress

Recently I saw something new (at least for me) in log file [% tools.ua.random() %] as below:

```
199.246.2.10 - - [21/Aug/2014:13:25:15 +0545] "POST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 200 2809 "http://mywebsite.com/wp-login.php" "[% tools.ua.random() %]"
64.34.173.227 - - [21/Aug/2014:13:25:32 +0545] "POST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 200 2809 "http://mywebsite.com/wp-login.php" "[% tools.ua.random() %]"
91.109.3.166 - - [21/Aug/2014:13:25:32 +0545] "POST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 200 2809 "http://mywebsite.com/wp-login.php" "[% tools.ua.random() %]"
```

If someone has seen similar kind of log can anybody explain me what is this and how to stop it, may be by applying some rule in modsec. I think it is some kind of software used for ddos attack. I found [this in web](http://blog.chr.istoph.de/wp-login-php-serverseitg-filtern/).

Comment: could it be somewhat brute force?
using tools.ua.random

Comment: This is getting bad as it is taking more CPU load. How to stop it from server side. Like if found "tools.ua.random" pattern drop it. BTW we have centos

Comment: You could drop requests containing that pattern using iptables or mod_security.

Comment: @Err0rr 64.34.173.227 and 91.109.3.166 are ips from hosting companies why would a server visit your site?? They are bots or people using VPNs so start blocking them now. What web server are you using?

Comment: @BigBob: those are definitely bots thats why I said "attack" and these are just samples there are lot more ips. I think this is user agent. However I am still searching for this and came to know that it is an user-agent and I somehow manage to stop it from .htaccess like below

# BLOCK USER AGENTS
RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "\[%\ tools\.ua\.random\(\)\ %\] [NC]
RewriteRule !^robots\.txt$ - [F]

# BLOCK BLANK USER AGENTS
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^-?$

Comment: above .htaccess didn't work but I get [.htaccess](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/blocking-useragent-toolsuarandom-brute-force-attack). This might work.

Comment: Modsecurity rule to block it, insert following in modsec2.conf file inside /etc/httpd/conf/

SecRule REQUEST_HEADERS:User-Agent "@pmFromFile bot.txt""id:350001,rev:1,severity:2,log,msg:'Bot Rule: Black Bot detected. '"

make bot.txt file in same location and write down the name of bots you want to stop in this file (may be one per line). Finally restart the httpd service. 

#service httpd graceful

Answer (score 2):

I think it is a poorly written robot. `[% tools.ua.random() %]` looks like a template that should pick a random user agent. But it does not substitute the value (the UA).
It must be a bad bot hiding behind various user agents.

To mitigate some attack against WordPress please take a look at my plugin:
https://github.com/szepeviktor/wordpress-plugin-construction/tree/master/wordpress-fail2ban
The plugin analyses the HTTP request line-by-line.

Use the "must use" (mu-plugin) version, that is the up-to-date one. I hope you understand commented PHP code. I would gladly help you to set this up. It even works without the fail2ban daemon (running on a Linux server) but it **is** designed to immediately block bads bot through fail2ban.

Comment: Thanks for the response. May be other people suffering from same problem will hit this page and get your answer. I wish your solution will be helpful and I love to give it a try.